# Find multiple match of the same string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$var1 = "ab:abc:abcd:ghi:jpq";
$var2 = "abcdefghi";
```

Considering the above variables. How can I get all occurrences of `var1` that matches the begining of `var2`, without doing splits and loops?

It does not matter how long `var2` is. Just as long as the beginning matches something in `var2`, each of those parts of `var1` should be added to `$matches`.

Also `var2` is an arguments passed to a function, while `var1` is a result of a one time search. So `var2`'s content is not static.

Comment: so your efforts and research as well.

Comment: Replace all `:` with `|`, surround the whole thing with `()` and add `^` in front. Use it with a regex function. No guarantee it will work for all cases, especially when there are special characters. You would need to split and quote each of the token... Aaaargg, why are we doing this again? Just do split and loop to check.

Comment: Tried that, and it only prints the first match. And yes a split/loop would work, but before doing that, I would rather make sure that there is no better and more efficient way. This search will be used several times, and loops are not always the fastest solution. If var1 contains 100 items and I do a starts-with check on each of them times 100 searches, it will amount to a lot of loops per request.

Comment: Regex will do essentially the same thing, plus overhead, plus the complexity you have to deal with when there are non-alphanumeric characters. If you want to optimize for speed, build a tree from $var1 to quickly locate which item in $var1 is the same as the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/(\bab)|(\babc)|(\babcd)|(\bghi)|(\bjpq)/g";
preg_match_all($pattern, $var2, $matches);
```